# Gulp EN0ENT missing directory error after clean task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm getting started with learning Gulp for a project.  I expect this is a newbie error, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
const { series, parallel, src, dest } = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');

function clean(cb) {
  del('./dist', cb())
}

function durp() {
  return src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(src('src/test.hbs'))
    .pipe(dest('./dist'));
}

exports.default = series(
  clean,
  parallel(
    durp,
  )
);
```

This is the error I am receiving.  It happens exactly every other time I run the script.  The following time I run it, it works fine. 
 Rinse, repeat:

```
$ gulp
[23:15:50] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/test/gulpfile.js
[23:15:50] Starting 'default'...
[23:15:50] Starting 'clean'...
[23:15:50] Finished 'clean' after 644 μs
[23:15:50] Starting 'durp'...
[23:15:50] 'durp' errored after 26 ms
[23:15:50] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './dist'
[23:15:50] 'default' errored after 29 ms

$ gulp
[23:15:51] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/test/gulpfile.js
[23:15:51] Starting 'default'...
[23:15:51] Starting 'clean'...
[23:15:51] Finished 'clean' after 431 μs
[23:15:51] Starting 'durp'...
[23:15:51] Finished 'durp' after 27 ms
[23:15:51] Finished 'default' after 30 ms

$
```

It's weird, because I wouldn't expect a race condition, since I'm running in series, and anyways the clean task is always running first.  Hrm.

Comment: Where does your `durp` task get invoked, and what is `libguides`?

Comment: @TheDancingCode oops, `libguides` was an artifact; should be `durp`.  :)  It was late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del` doesn't accept a callback, but returns a promise. Your `clean` function should be as follows:

```js
function clean() {
  return del('./dist');
}
```